# How to access the inline menu of the meeting request item

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I developed an outlook add-in which manages the meeting request response with a custom ribbon button. But this button in the ribbon. There is a standard meeting request menu in the meeting request body. I would like to hide this menu. But I cannot access this menu. I can access the selected item in the compact view with the code in the ThisAddin.cs

I have tried to access the active explorer. there are some of the controls accessible like command bars. But I don't know what this control means.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There buttons cannot be hidden. You can simulate clicks on them using Accessibility API, but that's about it.